# Creating a newsletter list for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have seen this question asked a lot with people seeking help with creating a newsletter system.

I have a newsletter mailer setup with the use of roadie gem. I need help with figuring out how to setup the subscriber part of the newsletter. I have been doing the newsletters by hand from a mail client so I have around 300 subscribers.

Can someone help me setup the code so that all registered users would automatically be subscribed to the newsletter and I can import my 300 email subscribers to the list. There should be a unsubscribe link also. Assistance would be extremely helpful to me and so many other people out there.

newsletter_mailer.rb:

```
class NewsletterMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def weekly(email)
    @newsletter = newsletter
    @recipient = recipient
    mail to: email, subject: "New Dates Weekly"
  end
```

Newsletter Controller:

```
def send
 @newsletter = Newsletter.find(:params['id'])
 @recipients = Recipient.all
 @recipients.each do |recipient|
   Newsletter.newsletter_email(recipient, @newsletter).deliver
 end
end
```

Users controller:

```
 def settings
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def profile
    @profile = User.profile
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])    
  end

    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need a one-to-one relation between `User` and `Recipient`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :recipient
  ...
end

class Recipient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

Then in your signup process, you just need to create the user's recipient:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    ...
    @user.create_recipient(:email => @user.email)
    ...
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one for more details on `has_one` methods like `create_association`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the classical `many-to-many` relationship.
In `Rails` it is realized by `has_and_belongs_to_many` often refered to as `habtm`.

A good start to learn about relationships are the [RubyOnRail-Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Basicly you need a `Newsletter` model and a `Subscriber` model and a table `newsletters_subscribers`.

```
class Newsletter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subscribers
end
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :newsletters
end
```

Comment: I understand relationships. I need more assistance with creating the code. I have some above but just need help with finishing it as I'm stuck on Point A and I need to get to Point Z.